# Does convergence of the sequence $f(x_n)$ imply convergence of the sequence $x_n$ for a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Similar questions have been raised previously on this platform; however, the simplicity of my answer makes me doubt if I have made a mistake.

This is the text of the exercise:
"Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and $n \mapsto x_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the sequence $n \mapsto f(x_n)$ is convergent. Is it true that the sequence $n \mapsto x_n$ is also convergent?"

---

I say this is not true.

Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = k$.
Let $x_n = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
The sequence $n \mapsto f(x_n) = k$ converges to k,
but the sequence $n \mapsto x_n$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: You haven't made clear what you are asking. Is this a solution-verification question?  If so, please ad that tag.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $f(x)=1 $ constant function. Of course
$x_{n}=(-1)^n$ is divergent. But $f(x_{n})$ is sequence of ones wich is convergent.

I suppose we need this function has to be injection additionally